# unexpected behavior of unix sort

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, tcsh

Hi I am trying to use unix sort function. I wanted to sort the file by 3rd column

Here are the content of the file

```
tcsh 541% cat file
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
```

When i try to sort it by column 1 it works

```
tcsh 533% sort -t, -nk1 file
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
```

When i try to sort it by column 2 it works.

```
tcsh 534% sort -t, -nk1 file | sort -t, -nk2
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
```

But when i try to sort it by column 3 it doesnt work

```
tcsh 535% sort -t, -nk1 file | sort -t, -nk3
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758

tcsh 532% sort -t, -nk3 file
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
```

The expected output is (updated based on Knitt's comment)

```
tcsh 532% sort -t, -nk3 file
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
```

SORT version :

542% sort --version sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>. This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert

Comment: Why are you sorting by column 1, then ignoring the result and resorting by column 2?

Comment: Why do you expect that 769 comes before 736? 769 is obviously numerically larger than 736, so the order should be 736, 769, 867

Comment: @arun If you have more information, click the Edit button and add it to the question, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: corrected the expected output @knittl

Comment: The output is expected here on Ubuntu 23.04 with GNU sort 8.32. Perhaps it's a locale thing? Try `LC_ALL=C sort …`

Comment: that worked for me. Got more information about LC_ALL at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @knittl suggested after below settings

```
setenv LC_ALL C
```

Getting expected output

```
tcsh 545% sort -t, -nk3 file
3,2636,736,700,700,700,1083,880,880,880,88,792,0,260,25439,7984,43758
2,2587,769,629,629,629,890,890,890,890,89,801,0,184,24944,8018,42839
1,2622,867,686,686,686,880,880,880,880,88,792,0,246,25551,7977,43721
```

Got more information about LC_ALL [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do)

Answer (score 0):

Following specification of the option `-k` fixes the problem :

```
sort -t, -nk3,3 file
```